# Exclude outliers when most scores are 0

Tags: outliers, skewness

I'm doing a word learning experiment for which I prefer my participants to have no prior knowledge of the words. Prior knowledge is determined by a pre-test. Most participants indeed know 0 words before the experiment, but some people do know a few. This is the total set of scores: 45x0, 3x1, 2x2, 1x3, 1x4, 1x5, 1x7 (n=54).

I want to exclude participants with 'too much' prior knowledge from the analysis. But how to determine what is too much? I'm aware of approaches using the mean +- 2 or 3 standard deviations, but it seems that they are not justified because the data are not normally distributed. Am I correct in this, and what might be a way to quantify exclusion criteria objectively?

Comment: It seems this is more of a practical than a statistical question.  How many words would someone have to know before you consider it "too much?"  I don't think the numbers alone can answer this, or even help really.  Suppose for instance everyone in your sample knew *every* word.  Is it okay to include them because they're not outliers in the sample?

Comment: That's a very helpful way to think about the issue. This would definitely not be okay, so I see that some subjectivity will necessarily be involved in this decision. However, please see my comment below for a follow-up question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way around the fact that "too" much is necessarily a subjective judgement call by you and you alone. So you just decide what your cut-off is and report it and your arguments in your article.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I do see your point. But the existence of methods such as mean +- 2 standard deviations suggest that the decision need not necessarily be subjective (apart from the subjectivity in deciding how many standard deviations you'd use as the cut-off point). Is it correct that I could not apply this approach to my data due to their non-normal distribution?

Comment: @Johanna: The +-2 standard deviation rule is a completely subjective way to remove outliers. As Marten Buis pointed out, you just have to be 100% objective in reporting how you modified your original sample. Applying the empirical rule is a bit strange because you are concerned only with the large values, not with the low ones. But it is definitely less problematic than to select the sample with lowest p-value...